# angular2-multiselect-dropdown badgeShowLimit option not working

Tags: angular, typescript, multi-select

I'm trying to templating selected items in angular2-multiselect-dropdown component, but when I set the badgeShowLimit to, for example, 5 , I can correctly see +1, +2 etc... in selected items label area when i select 6, 7 elements, but the component keeps on adding new labels for each selected items in the same area.

[screenshot](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5563736/72741371-c772fb00-3ba7-11ea-9551-4c89b6508b84.JPG)

.ts:

```
this.dropdownSettings = {
        singleSelection: false,
        text: 'select OAs',
        enableSearchFilter: true,
        classes: 'angular2-multiselect',
        showCheckbox: true,
        enableCheckAll: false,
        searchBy: ['riadName', 'riadCode' ],
        primaryKey: 'riadCode',
        badgeShowLimit: 5
      };
```

.html:

```
<angular2-multiselect [data]="observedAgents" [(ngModel)]="selectedOas" [settings]="dropdownSettings"
                (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelect($event)"
                style="min-height: 30px !important; font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif !important; font-size: 14px !important;">
                <c-item>
                    <ng-template let-item="item">
                        <label
                            style="color: #333;min-width: 150px; font-weight: normal !important; font-size: 12px !important;">{{item.riadName}}</label>
                    </ng-template>
                </c-item>
                <c-badge>                      
                    <ng-template let-item="item">                          
                        <label
                            style="margin: 0px; background-color: #4076BF; color: #FFF; 
                            font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal !important;">
                            {{item.riadName}}
                        </label>
                    </ng-template>                    
                </c-badge>
            </angular2-multiselect>
```

Any idea?